# Push custom fields to metadata of PDF using fscrawler

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika, fscrawler

I am using fscrawler to index PDF documents using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/fscrawler --config_dir /home/user1/conf test_index --restart --loop 1
```

The metadata of PDF is indexed.  I want to add custom fields towards the metadata of PDF and index these too.  I have adapted the configuration file as follows:

```
metadata:
  custom_field1:
    type: text
  custom_field2:
    type: keyword
```

How to index these custom fields together with PDF using fscrawler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch with some set processors inside and tell FSCrawler to use this pipeline. There's an example of this [in the documentation](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/elasticsearch.html#using-ingest-node-pipeline).

Would that work for you? If not, I think we should support the indexation of specific metadata per file, by checking if a file named `foo.pdf.metadata` for example exists in a side folder with all the metadata files in it... I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/issues/1659) for it.

Otherwise, the REST Service of FSCrawler could allow [adding metadata to the files](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/rest.html#additional-tags).